# Reset CSS styles for a DIV and all nested elements

Tags: html, css

How can I reset all styles for only a div and all nested elements? I have tried all the below solutions, but none of them are working for me. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried using all three css classes below, and none of them remove the background.

[Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

[Reset css styles for only div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312330/reset-css-styles-for-only-div)

**Here's my code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestResetCSS.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestResetCSS.TestResetCSS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .remove-all-styles {
            all: initial;
        }

        .yui3-cssreset html{color:#000;background:#FFF}.yui3-cssreset body,.yui3-cssreset div,.yui3-cssreset dl,.yui3-cssreset dt,.yui3-cssreset dd,.yui3-cssreset ul,.yui3-cssreset ol,.yui3-cssreset li,.yui3-cssreset h1,.yui3-cssreset h2,.yui3-cssreset h3,.yui3-cssreset h4,.yui3-cssreset h5,.yui3-cssreset h6,.yui3-cssreset pre,.yui3-cssreset code,.yui3-cssreset form,.yui3-cssreset fieldset,.yui3-cssreset legend,.yui3-cssreset input,.yui3-cssreset textarea,.yui3-cssreset p,.yui3-cssreset blockquote,.yui3-cssreset th,.yui3-cssreset td{margin:0;padding:0}.yui3-cssreset table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}.yui3-cssreset fieldset,.yui3-cssreset img{border:0}.yui3-cssreset address,.yui3-cssreset caption,.yui3-cssreset cite,.yui3-cssreset code,.yui3-cssreset dfn,.yui3-cssreset em,.yui3-cssreset strong,.yui3-cssreset th,.yui3-cssreset var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}.yui3-cssreset ol,.yui3-cssreset ul{list-style:none}.yui3-cssreset caption,.yui3-cssreset th{text-align:left}.yui3-cssreset h1,.yui3-cssreset h2,.yui3-cssreset h3,.yui3-cssreset h4,.yui3-cssreset h5,.yui3-cssreset h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}.yui3-cssreset q:before,.yui3-cssreset q:after{content:''}.yui3-cssreset abbr,.yui3-cssreset acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}.yui3-cssreset sup{vertical-align:text-top}.yui3-cssreset sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}.yui3-cssreset input,.yui3-cssreset textarea,.yui3-cssreset select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit}.yui3-cssreset input,.yui3-cssreset textarea,.yui3-cssreset select{*font-size:100%}.yui3-cssreset legend{color:#000}#yui3-css-stamp.cssreset-context{display:none}

        .reset-this {
            animation : none;
            animation-delay : 0;
            animation-direction : normal;
            animation-duration : 0;
            animation-fill-mode : none;
            animation-iteration-count : 1;
            animation-name : none;
            animation-play-state : running;
            animation-timing-function : ease;
            backface-visibility : visible;
            background : 0;
            background-attachment : scroll;
            background-clip : border-box;
            background-color : transparent;
            background-image : none;
            background-origin : padding-box;
            background-position : 0 0;
            background-position-x : 0;
            background-position-y : 0;
            background-repeat : repeat;
            background-size : auto auto;
            border : 0;
            border-style : none;
            border-width : medium;
            border-color : inherit;
            border-bottom : 0;
            border-bottom-color : inherit;
            border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
            border-bottom-style : none;
            border-bottom-width : medium;
            border-collapse : separate;
            border-image : none;
            border-left : 0;
            border-left-color : inherit;
            border-left-style : none;
            border-left-width : medium;
            border-radius : 0;
            border-right : 0;
            border-right-color : inherit;
            border-right-style : none;
            border-right-width : medium;
            border-spacing : 0;
            border-top : 0;
            border-top-color : inherit;
            border-top-left-radius : 0;
            border-top-right-radius : 0;
            border-top-style : none;
            border-top-width : medium;
            bottom : auto;
            box-shadow : none;
            box-sizing : content-box;
            caption-side : top;
            clear : none;
            clip : auto;
            color : inherit;
            columns : auto;
            column-count : auto;
            column-fill : balance;
            column-gap : normal;
            column-rule : medium none currentColor;
            column-rule-color : currentColor;
            column-rule-style : none;
            column-rule-width : none;
            column-span : 1;
            column-width : auto;
            content : normal;
            counter-increment : none;
            counter-reset : none;
            cursor : auto;
            direction : ltr;
            display : inline;
            empty-cells : show;
            float : none;
            font : normal;
            font-family : inherit;
            font-size : medium;
            font-style : normal;
            font-variant : normal;
            font-weight : normal;
            height : auto;
            hyphens : none;
            left : auto;
            letter-spacing : normal;
            line-height : normal;
            list-style : none;
            list-style-image : none;
            list-style-position : outside;
            list-style-type : disc;
            margin : 0;
            margin-bottom : 0;
            margin-left : 0;
            margin-right : 0;
            margin-top : 0;
            max-height : none;
            max-width : none;
            min-height : 0;
            min-width : 0;
            opacity : 1;
            orphans : 0;
            outline : 0;
            outline-color : invert;
            outline-style : none;
            outline-width : medium;
            overflow : visible;
            overflow-x : visible;
            overflow-y : visible;
            padding : 0;
            padding-bottom : 0;
            padding-left : 0;
            padding-right : 0;
            padding-top : 0;
            page-break-after : auto;
            page-break-before : auto;
            page-break-inside : auto;
            perspective : none;
            perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
            position : static;
            /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
            quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
            right : auto;
            tab-size : 8;
            table-layout : auto;
            text-align : inherit;
            text-align-last : auto;
            text-decoration : none;
            text-decoration-color : inherit;
            text-decoration-line : none;
            text-decoration-style : solid;
            text-indent : 0;
            text-shadow : none;
            text-transform : none;
            top : auto;
            transform : none;
            transform-style : flat;
            transition : none;
            transition-delay : 0s;
            transition-duration : 0s;
            transition-property : none;
            transition-timing-function : ease;
            unicode-bidi : normal;
            vertical-align : baseline;
            visibility : visible;
            white-space : normal;
            widows : 0;
            width : auto;
            word-spacing : normal;
            z-index : auto;
        } 

        .dashBackgroundColor {
            background: #ccd3e0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dashBackgroundColor">
        <div class="remove-all-styles">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <span>testing</span>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The background is set on a parent element .dashBackgroundColor that's why.

Comment: I guess I may have been looking at the wrong solutions then. My goal is to remove/reset all properties being inherited by a DIV and all its nested elements.

Comment: Your question is unclear, background is not a inherited property anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't asssigned reset-this class to any div.
assign reset-this class to remove-all-styles class div

```
<div class="dashBackgroundColor">
        <div class="remove-all-styles reset-this">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <span>testing</span>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: My goal is to remove all styles being inherited from above. So my goal is to remove the dashBackgroundColor in this example.

Comment: What is your use case, maybe there is another approach to your problem, I tried using shadow DOM but that is also not solving your problem.