# How to block outer CSS to modify div

Tags: javascript, css

Scenario

`Visit this link for Code`https://plnkr.co/edit/yjGTX0XvOZIqL17Co2MF?p=info

I do not want my innerDiv to get modified by CSS in outerDiv.
Is there some way to achieve this?

(contents(HTML) of InnerDiv are loaded via ajax call , and the resulting page already has its own CSS and both CSS files are messing up all the layouts and formats)

Comment: try to use iframe

Comment: iframe not working sir.

Comment: No because the main Div is its parent, and a child element always inherits some of its parents basic properties (content-related mostly) unless told otherwise. If you want the child element to have different properties, you'd have to manually set them.

Comment: Also, Iframe is not suitable for your case. It doesn't even make sense including a whole page just to get that result.

Comment: Kelvin, yes I know it , but that's the hard way.I have to do a lot of work to achieve this.

Comment: @Deepanshu You may not like Kelvin's explanation, but I believe that it is the correct answer to your question, which is "no, it can't be done". There is no easy way!

Comment: @Jonathan-Nicol , its not like 'I do not like his answer' , all I want to know was 'if there exist some easy way to do this'.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the tone of your comment. Your only options if you want to avoid CSS conflicts are to make sure your AJAX loaded content doesn't match selectors in the parent document's stylesheet, or override any conflicting rules with more specific selectors, as described in the existing answers to this question.

Comment: @Jonathan-Nicol Sir that is the real issue, 
I got your point, but the problem is my InnerDiv is having 20-30 CSS files each having 300-400+ lines of code, same goes with Outer Div. Now both are conflicting because of loading both on same page.
(both were being loaded on different pages before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15380121/137626): `all: initial` isn't supported by Edge (Safari is finally OK)

1. So you can reset manually a [hundred of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943609/reset-css-styles-for-a-div-and-all-nested-elements) if you really really really want to be sure (forget the most obscure ones you know you don't use. If you're a third party, well no luck).
2. You can (should) add the `!important` modifier (that's one of those cases where it isn't possible to do in some other way... Fine for me at least)
3. You can also add a whole lot of specificity to your selectors by adding an id to your component's parent and prefix each of your selectors with that id: `#myComponent.my-component .my-component-descendant { color: #333 !important; }`. If your existing CSS already uses id (*meh*), you can go even further (*lower*, quality wise) and use the same id multiple times in a single selector. `#myComponent#myComponent#myComponent.my-component .my-component-descendant { color: #333 !important; }`. What is one the crappiest thing you can imagine in a sane project is also a powerful tool when you *need* to add "enough" specificity.

Food for thought: the modern way of setting `box-sizing` by setting it on :root and then letting inheritance do its job can be helpful (or not) https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/
Advantage: if you set another value on a descendant, descendants of the latter will inherit from it. You now have a whole part of your DOM inheriting from another value.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the properties in you innerdiv; here I have overwritten the background-color property of the outerdiv

```css
#outerMostDiv {background-color:red;}
#innerDiv {background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="outerMostDiv">
<!-- SOME CSS HERE (say Outer CSS)-->
   outer div
    <div id="innerDiv">
    <!-- some CSS HERE -->
    innerdiv
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got your point, but the problem is my InnerDiv is having 20-30 CSS files each having 300-400+ lines of code, same goes for Outer Div.
Now both are conflicting because of loading both on same page.

Comment: 20-30 files? M sorry , I dont it is a good practise to have dependencies in 20 different css files;  How will u even debug; My advice, please consolidate those numerous files; else u might end up with spaghetti code.

or a hacky route: find all the css (of the innerdiv) that shouldnt be overriden, put them in separate css file and append this css file after all other files.